# Почему при открытии главной страницы сайта посылается 2 запроса в AstraLinux?

Tags: yii2, apache, curl, astra-linux, kerberos

Есть **AstraLinux** с доменной авторизацией. Разрабатываемый сайт идет на **Yii2**. Почему при открытии главной страницы появляется 2 запроса, и как от этого избавиться?. Причем, выпилил **Yii2** в принципе из `/var/www/html`, но запросы остались такие же.

При отправке curl запроса Yii2 выдает ошибку по БД GSSAPI, а если убрать Yii2, то все работает исправно. В чем проблема может быть? Понятно, что он не может получить **negotiate** токен, но с чего бы вдруг?

**Обновление**

Проверил на чистых запросах без Yii2 - все работает. То есть, где-то Yii2 теряет момент с:

```php
$KRB5CCNAME = $_SERVER['KRB5CCNAME'] ?? '';

putenv("KRB5CCNAME={$KRB5CCNAME}");
```

Или тут просто нет **KRB5CCNAME** в `$_SERVER`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге оказалось, что это поведение только на определенной версии FireFox 52

Answer (score 1):

Короче, если вы используете **Kerberos** вместе с **Yii2**, а также доменную авторизацию **AstraLinux**, то авторизация (подключение) к БД должна быть типа:

```
'db' => [
    'class' => Connection::class,
    'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=host;dbname=dbname',
    'username' => null,
    'charset' => 'utf8',
],
```

Обратите внимание, что пользователь **NULL**. А предварительный конфиг в установке `putenv('KRB5CCNAME')` вообще не нужна...

Очень странная логика работы!